# Type comparison: 'QuestionType' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: angular, typescript

for some reason I can't compare a type. I have the following domain class:

```
export type QuestionType = 'TextOnly'
  | 'RadioListQuestion'
  | 'DropDownListQuestion'
  | 'CheckBoxQuestion'
  | 'NumberQuestion'
  | 'DateQuestion'
  | 'TextQuestion'
  | 'QuestionGroup';
```

And in my component I want to compare against that type like this:

```
if(question.type == QuestionType.QuestionGroup.) {
   // some logic here
}
```

But it throws a compile error:

```
'QuestionType' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

Can anyone please point me to the right solution?

@Update as @betadeveloper adviced I added a type check in the method defintion, which doesn't work unfortunately:

```
formGroupStructure = questionGroup.questions.reduce((accumulator, question: { type: QuestionType }) => {

        // If it's a nested question group (QuestionGroup inside questions[])
        if(question.type === 'QuestionGroup') {

          const formGroupStructure = this.createQuestionGroupFormGroupStructure(question.questionGroup);

          const segmentControl: AbstractControl = formGroup.get(tab.id)['controls'][segment.id];
          (<FormGroup>segmentControl).addControl(segment.questionGroup.id, this.formBuilder.group(formGroupStructure));
        } else {

          // treat normal questions: Add them to the accumulator
          if (isQuestionAnswerable(question)) {
            accumulator[question.id] = [
              question.selection,
              question.isMandatory ? [Validators.required] : [],
            ];
          }

        }

        return accumulator;
  }, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just import and use the exact type. In your example, you can do:

```
if(question.type == QuestionGroup) {
   // some logic here
}
```